# Is it OK for a class constructor to block forever?

Tags: c++, multithreading, constructor, infinite-loop

Let's say I have an object that provides some sort of functionality in an infinite loop.

Is is acceptable to just put the infinite loop in the constructor?

Example:

```
class Server {
    public:
    Server() {
        for(;;) {
            //...
        }
    }
};
```

Or is there an inherent initialization problem in C++ if the constructor never completes?

(The idea is that to run a server you just say `Server server;`, possibly in a thread somewhere...)

Comment: I don't think there's anything _wrong_ with it but it's probably going to be confusing to users of your class. What's wrong with just putting the loop in a `server::run` function or similar?

Comment: @Peter It just seems cleaner.  Why would you create a server and not run it immediately?

Comment: Because most people (I assume) don't expect constructors to be blocking, let alone never return.

Comment: I am pretty sure your object is not valid until the constructor has run, so any access to your object from elsewhere would likely be undefined behavior.

Comment: Can you not just write a single function?

Comment: This is technically fine, but is IMHO a code smell. According to the single-responsibility principle, I wouldn't expect `Server server;` to create *and run* the server. `Server server; server.run();` is way more readable and maintainable.

Comment: What about the RAII principle?  What use is a server between creation and running?

Comment: There is a potential problem, by C++ language rules virtual functions don't behave virtual as long as the constructor has not completed.

Comment: @HansPassant -- virtual functions called in a constructor (and a destructor) are dispatched virtually up to the class whose constructor (destructor) is running, so for what looks like a final class, this isn't a problem. The problem occurs if there's a class derived from `Server` that overrides virtual functions; virtual calls in the code running in the constructor (destructor) won't go to the derived-class versions.

Comment: Note that this would necessitate a rewrite of calling code if `Server`'s design changes in the future, or if the object ever needs to be replaced with one that _doesn't_ rely on the constructor in this exact manner.

Comment: Blocking forever inside a constructor sounds like something which would likely violate the [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It's not wrong per standard, it's just a bad design.

Constructors don't usually block. Their purpose is to take a raw chunk of memory, and transform it into a valid C++ object. Destructors do the opposite: they take valid C++ objects and turn them back into raw chunks of memory.

If your constructor blocks forever (emphasis on forever), it does something different than just turn a chunk of memory into an object.
It's ok to block for a short time (a mutex is a perfect example of it), if this serves the construction of the object.
In your case, it looks like your constructor is accepting and serving clients. This is not turning memory into objects.

I suggest you split the constructor into a "real" constructor that builds a server object and another `start` method that serves clients (by starting an event loop).

ps: In some cases you *have* to execute the functionality/logic of the object separately from the constructor, for example if your class inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: I'm with you in general, although it seems that modern constructors do not *always* just turn memory into objects.  Your mutex example is one for example, or another example is the C++ thread constructor which launches the given function immediately.  One could argue that creating a server is the role of the constructor...

Comment: A few things: 1) `std::thread` has some bad decisions behind it. this is why `std::jthread` was standardized. 2) I actuall would prefer the thread object to have a start method 3) It's true that sometimes we abuse our own principles. Software engineering principles are rules of thumb - usually they help us. seldomly, we break them because they hinder us from doing something simpler and more correct.

Comment: Opening a file is something you might legitimately do in an RAII constructor; that can block for I/O for pathname lookup, potentially tens of milliseconds, or hundreds of ms on a heavily loaded system.  Or whole seconds to spin up a magnetic drive that was idle.  (Or NFS mount a server on mars...)

Comment: @CaptainCodeman is correct: RAII says a constructor should be more than just memory manipulation.

Comment: @PaulDraper: Emphasis on _forever_. Blocking to acquire a resource is _very_ different from blocking _forever_.

Comment: I've never said that construction is purely "memory manipulation", that's shallowing of my argument.

Comment: You also should note that no derived constructors will be called at this point (and that means unchanged virtual functions too), meaning that deriving from this class wouldn't tweak its workings. So, just don't do this.

Answer (score 18):

It's allowed. But like any other infinite loop, it [must have observable side effects](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Progress_guarantee), otherwise you get [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Calling the networking functions counts as "observable side effects", so you're safe. This rule only bans loops that either do literally nothing, or just shuffle data around without interacting with the outside world.

Comment: Thank you.  What is UB?

Comment: @CaptainCodeman Undefined behavior. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub It's what the standard calls various unpredictable behavior that happens when you break certain rules of the language (anything can happen; including code working as expected, possibly until some unrelated thing changes).

Comment: @CaptainCodeman - [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](https://blog.llvm.org/posts/2011-05-13-what-every-c-programmer-should-know/)

Answer (score 16):

Its legal, but its a good idea to avoid it.

The main issue is that you should avoid surprising users.  Its unusual to have a constructor that never returns because it isn't logical.  Why would you construct something you can never use?  As such, while the pattern may work, it is unlikely to be an expected behavior.

A secondary issue is that it limits how your Server class can be used.  The construction and destruction processes of C++ are fundamental to the language, so hijacking them can be tricky.  For example, one might want to have a `Server` that is the member of a class, but now that overarching class' constructor will block... even if that isn't intuitive.  It also makes it very difficult to put these objects into containers, as this can involve allocating many objects.

The closest I can think of to what you are doing is that of `std::thread`.  Thread does not block forever, but it does have a constructor that does a surprisingly large amount of work.  But if you look at `std::thread`, you realize that when it comes to multithreading, being surprised is the norm, so people have less trouble with such choices.  (I am not personally aware of the reasons for starting the thread upon construction, but there's so many corner cases in multithreading that I would not be surprised if it resolves some of them)

Answer (score 4):

A user might expect to set up your `Server` object in the main thread. Then call the `server.endless_loop()` function within a worker thread.

In an actual server, the process of acquiring a port requires escalated privileges which can then be dropped. Or perhaps you have an object that needs to load settings. Those sort of tasks could take place in the main thread before the long term looping takes place elsewhere.

Personally, I'd prefer your object had a "poll" function that was fast and non blocking. You could then have a loop function that called poll and sleep in an endless loop. You might even have an atomic variable that you can set to exit the loop from a different thread. Another feature would be to launch an internal thread within the Server object.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, there's nothing "wrong" with this as far as C++ semantics are concerned, but it's poor design. The point of a constructor is to construct an object, so if that task never completes then it will be surprising to users.

Others have made suggestions regarding splitting the construction & run steps into constructor and method, which makes sense if you have other things you might want to do with the Server besides run it, or if you actually might want to construct it, do other stuff, and then run it.

But if you expect the caller will always just do `Server server; server.run()`, then maybe you don't even need a *class* -- it could just be a stand-alone function `run_server()`. If you don't have state to encapsulate and pass around in the first place, then you don't necessarily need objects. A stand-alone function can even be marked `[[noreturn]]` to make it clear both to the user and the compiler that the function never returns.

It's hard to say which makes more sense without knowing more about your use case. But in short: constructors construct objects -- if you're doing something else, don't use them for that.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, your code has no problem. Because of the following rule:

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type ([basic.types]) (or complete type) at the closing } of the class-specifier. Within the class member-specification, the class is regarded as complete within function bodies, default arguments, noexcept-specifiers, and default member initializers (including such things in nested classes). Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete within its own class member-specification.

However, A restriction for your code is that you cannot use a glvalue that doesn't obtain from pointer `this` to access this object due to the behavior is unspecified. It's governed by this rule:

> During the construction of an object, if the value of the object or any of its subobjects is accessed through a glvalue that is not obtained, directly or indirectly, from the constructor's this pointer, the value of the object or subobject thus obtained is unspecified.

Moreover, you cannot use the utility `shared_ptr` to manage such class objects. In general, place an infinitely loop into a constructor is not a good idea. Many restrictions will apply to the object when you use it.